# Sort mixed value strings "numerically"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sorting

I am looking for a way to sort house numbers. The numbers are stored as strings, as while most are numeric some have a letter appended. For example:

- 1002
- 29C
- 1
- 205
- 105A

Is there a way to have these ordered as per the below?

- 1
- 29C
- 105A
- 205
- 1002

Comment: Is it in table or what..??

Comment: Sorry, yes, these are values in a table

Comment: Are you using Sql Server, MySql, Oracle or what..??

Comment: Ok..then I just posted the answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you want: I hope you are using `SQL SERVER`

```
select * from tbl order by 
case when 
    PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',val) = 0 
THEN 
    val
ELSE
    cast(Left(val,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',val)-1) as int) 
END
```

### [Live Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f83535/3)

Answer (score 0):

Another method

```
select * from tbl order by
stuff(val+'a',patindex('%[^0-9]%',val+'a'),len(val),'')*1
```